# CSS inset and out box shadow

Tags: html, css

I need inset and outer shadow at a box for a menu.

How can i do that?

Here is my CSS:

```
li.menu-list:hover {
border:solid 0.1rem white;
background-color: rgba(26, 67, 119, 0.8);
box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0.2rem white;  
box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0.3rem white inset;
}
```

Comment: use commas to add many box-shadow parameters

Comment: like `box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0.2rem white, 0 0 1rem 0.3rem white inset;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this as you are overwriting your original value. What you should do is this:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0.2rem white, 0 0 1rem 0.3rem white inset;
```

By adding another `box-shadow` declaration, you are actually resetting the box shadow and implementing another one, so only one shows up. CSS3 has a lot of these new-fangled options and they can all be chained together using commas to separate them.